# Rails integration test failed because the final slash of the current_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I`m writing a integration test using capybara, here the code of my test.

```
test "when providing invalid data" do
    admin = create(:administrator)
    signin_administrator_as admin.email, admin.password

    visit new_admin_country_path

    click_button t("buttons.admin.save")

    assert_equal admin_countries_path, current_path
    assert page.has_text? t("admin.form_error_message")
end
```

In the controller

```
def create
  @country = Country.new(country_params)

  if @country.save
    redirect_to admin_countries_path, notice: t("flash.admin.country.create.notice")
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I have a partial with my form that I use to insert and update

```
<%= form_for @country, url: admin_country_path(@country) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :code, t("labels.country.code") %>
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :portuguese_name, t("labels.country.portuguese_name") %>
    <%= f.text_field :portuguese_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :spanish_name, t("labels.country.spanish_name") %>
    <%= f.text_field :spanish_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :english_name, t("labels.country.english_name") %>
    <%= f.text_field :english_name %>
  </p>

  <%= f.submit t("buttons.admin.save") %>
<% end %>
```

But my test failed because the final slash of the url.

```
Expected: "/admin/countries"
Actual: "/admin/countries/"
```

this is my routes definition

```
namespace :admin do
    root to: "signin#new"

    get "/signin", to: "signin#new"
    post "/signin", to: "signin#create"

    get "/dashboard", to: "dashboard#index"

    resources :countries
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show routes settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form is using a route that points to the show page, instead of pointing it to the `POST /admin/countries` endpoint.

You have two options: change the url to `admin_countries_path` or simplifying the route by using only `<%= form_tag [:admin, @country] do %>`; the `:admin` refers to the endpoint, so Rails can correctly infer the whole route for your resource.